# What is the Universal Rating System (URS)?

Tags: rating

While watching this year's [2020 Champions Showdown Chess 9LX](https://youtu.be/f4qCYtkZMnU) I noticed they gave players' ratings according to the URS or Universal Rating System. Which are the characteristics of this rating system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Universal Rating System](http://universalrating.com/) is an alternate rating system which, according to the project's web site:

> The Universal Rating System™ (URS™ for short), is a revolutionary new
> sport’s rating system designed to assess the relative strength of
> participants across a wide variety of competitor vs competitor sports
> or games.
>
> The URS™ was developed as the result of a collaborative research
> project funded by the Grand Chess Tour, the Kasparov Chess Foundation
> and the Chess Club and Scholastic Center of Saint Louis.

According to the project's [FAQ page](http://universalrating.com/faqs.php), the major differences between URS ratings and FIDE Elo ratings are:

> There are many differences between the URS™ and the FIDE system. The
> most striking difference is that the URS™ calculates only one rating
> for each player, informed by their results at all rates of play. This
> published rating is the URS™ system's assessment of each player's
> strength at Classical chess (defined as a rate of play where each
> player has at least 2 hours for their first 60 moves). The URS™
> recognizes that there is useful information about a player's
> over-the-board chess strength in all game results regardless of the
> time limit, and can therefore more effectively estimate a player's
> Classical chess strength by also considering their results at games
> played at faster time controls. As the speed of play increases, the
> URS™ assigns less and less importance to the game results relative to
> games played at slower time controls.
>
> Furthermore, the URS™ is a weighted performance rating, calculated
> across several years of previous game results for all players. Older
> games are given less importance than more recent games, by applying an
> exponential decay rate. Unlike traditional performance ratings, which
> are based upon the opponents' rating at the time the game was played,
> the URS™ constantly reassesses the strength of all opponents and
> searches for the most likely set of current ratings for all players,
> in order to best explain the observed results.